# error during sbt execution: java.nio.channels.overlappingfilelockexception from windows command prompt

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to install sbt on windows 7 but testing it, I get the following error:

```
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(Unknown Source)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:88)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Checks.java:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:266)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.retrieve$1(Launch.scala:136)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$3.apply(Launch.scala:144)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:129)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:165)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:82)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:80)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:60)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
    at SbtJansiLaunch.main(SbtJansiLaunch.java:4)
Error during sbt execution: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
```

which seems related to the fact that I do have access to my remote HOME drive according to this post:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/lJvOvZ5RUwE

I tried to follow what they suggest, but I have never found any `sbt.boot.properties` file. I have also tried to overwrite the boot and working dir via:

```
 sbt -sbt-dir C:\my\new\home -sbt-boot C:\my\new\home
```

Would any of you have gone through all these problems and could have a step-by-step recipy to solve that ?

Comment: were you able to fix this issue ? I too have same problem but worked initially.

Comment: the sbt.boot.properties file is part of the sbt-launch.jar archive. Open it with an archive tool like winzip or 7zip and then look in the folder /sbt.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I had the same problem. The sbt.boot.properties file resides inside the sbt-launch.jar archive. Open it with an archive tool like winzip or 7zip and then look in the folder /sbt and you will see the sbt.boot.properties file.

The current version looks like this

```
[scala]
  version: ${sbt.scala.version-auto}

[app]
  org: ${sbt.organization-org.scala-sbt}
  name: sbt
  version: ${sbt.version-read(sbt.version)[0.13.6]}
  class: ${sbt.main.class-sbt.xMain}
  components: xsbti,extra
  cross-versioned: ${sbt.cross.versioned-false}
  resources: ${sbt.extraClasspath-}

[repositories]
  local
  typesafe-ivy-releases: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext], bootOnly
  maven-central

[boot]
  directory: ${sbt.boot.directory-${sbt.global.base-${user.home}/.sbt}/boot/}

[ivy]
  ivy-home: ${sbt.ivy.home-${user.home}/.ivy2/}
  checksums: ${sbt.checksums-sha1,md5}
  override-build-repos: ${sbt.override.build.repos-false}
  repository-config: ${sbt.repository.config-${sbt.global.base-${user.home}/.sbt}/repositories}
```

Make sure you add the property lock in the [boot] section or you will get another error. So eventually it should look like this:

```
[scala]
  version: ${sbt.scala.version-auto}

[app]
  org: ${sbt.organization-org.scala-sbt}
  name: sbt
  version: ${sbt.version-read(sbt.version)[0.13.6]}
  class: ${sbt.main.class-sbt.xMain}
  components: xsbti,extra
  cross-versioned: ${sbt.cross.versioned-false}
  resources: ${sbt.extraClasspath-}

[repositories]
  local
  typesafe-ivy-releases: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext], bootOnly
  maven-central

[boot]
  directory: ${sbt.boot.directory-${sbt.global.base-${user.home}/.sbt}/boot/}
  lock: false

[ivy]
  ivy-home: ${sbt.ivy.home-${user.home}/.ivy2/}
  checksums: ${sbt.checksums-sha1,md5}
  override-build-repos: ${sbt.override.build.repos-false}
  repository-config: ${sbt.repository.config-${sbt.global.base-${user.home}/.sbt}/repositories}
```

Another point of attention is also what they said on that google group. Do not run two sbt processes at the same time, as this parameter might cause inconsistencies then.

Comment: I think the having -Dsbt.boot.lock=false should work as well. If not, open a ticket :)